# Passing a class object to different functions

Tags: php

really I am looking for a bit of advice as to the best way to achieve something. I am working in pure PHP without any libraries.  I have a simple Config class

```
<?php

class Config
{
   //define my constants
}
```

This class is in a folder outside of the web root.  Within my web root, I have a simple PHP file that will act as a script, no need for it to be a class.  Instead of showing bit by bit, I will just show my thought process

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . "/../config/Config.php";

$config = new Config();
execute($config);

function execute($config) {
    $textFile = $this->obtainTextFile($config);
    $transferFile = $this->transferFile($config, $textFile);
}

function obtainTextFile($config) {
    //connect to database and write results to text file

    return $textFile;  //path to the generated file
}  

function transferFile($config, $textFile) {
    //return whether the file was successfully SFTP
}
```

So firstly I require the config file.  I then create a `$config` object which I pass to the execute function.  The execute function essentially acts as the entry point.  Now this function has the object, it needs to pass it to another couple of functions that need the object.  To me this seems a bit strange because if it was a class, I could just refer to the class variable.

Is this the normal way of doing things when not using a class?  Is there a better way of doing this whereby I dont have to keep passing the object around, without using a class?

Any advice appreciated

Comment: You say `no need for it to be a class` and then you have `$textFile = $this->obtainTextFile($config);` What is `$this` supposed to refer to if `execute()` is just a function and not a class method?

Comment: `$this` is used to refer to the instance of the class when you're executing code within that instance.... it is meaningless when your code isn't class code

Comment: Sorry, was just testing a few things and forgot to remove $this

Comment: There are a few ways some good some bad, the better way, put the functions in a class (maybe break them up IoC) and pass it once, if yo got more classes maybe use a registry pattern, turn Config class into a static class or use a facade, or which is not good use $GLOBALS['config'], or define `global $config` in the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that, create two classes. One is the Config and the other one is the Application that does all the magic.
And then you have one script file that uses both classes.

**Application class**

```
class Application {

    /** @var Config **/
    private $config;

    public function __construct(Config $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->transferFile($this->obtainTextFile());
    }

    private function obtainTextFile() {
        //connect to database and write results to text file

        return $textFile;  //path to the generated file
    }  

    private function transferFile($textFile) {
        //return whether the file was successfully SFTP
    }
}
```

**Script file**

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . "/../config/Config.php";
require __DIR__ . "/../Application.php";

$config = new Config();
$app = new Application($config);
$app->execute();
```